# Hide stream url in HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html, html5-audio

I use this code below to hide stream url of songs for my wordpress site … this mean instead of: example.com/audio.mp3 url is example.com/streem.php?id=53502

I have tested it with default HTML 5 player and it works on chrome and IE, but this is not working with this player: http://goo.gl/HziDr

Can anybody tell me is my code ok?

Code of streem.php is:

```
<?php
require('./wp-config.php');  
$wp->init();  
$wp->parse_request();  
$wp->query_posts();  
$wp->register_globals(); 
$attachmentID = $_GET['id'];
$attachment = get_attached_file( $attachmentID , false );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Content-Length: '. (string)filesize($attachment)); // provide file size
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
readfile($attachment);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that player, but it's possible that it isn't content-type aware and requires a file extension to work.  You could append

'&fmt=.mp3'

to your URL and see if that helps.  Your PHP script should ignore that query parameter but hopefully the player will see the .mp3 extension and then work.